# How to change the stroke width of a shape programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, shapes

This is circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/> 
    <padding android:left="30dp" android:top="30dp"
             android:right="30dp" android:bottom="30dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#439CC8" android:width="7dp" />
</shape>
```

This is my code:

```java
textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
```

I want to change the stroke thickness in my java code. How can I change it programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to create it programmatically

```
ShapeDrawable circle = new ShapeDrawable( new  OvalShape() );
```

you need to set the properties after this, ( padding, color, etc) then change its stroke

```
circle.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(12);
```

then set it as the background for the view

```
textview.setBackgroundDrawable(circle);
```

Comment: myView --- what is this variable?

Comment: whatever view you are trying to set the background on.  textview in your case. ill update my answer

Comment: My app stopped this line : ShapeDrawable myCircle =  (ShapeDrawable) getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.circle );

Comment: 12-15 16:52:13.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable

Comment: i've updated my answer, you'll probably have to do this programmatically

Comment: but i want to change stroke width for "circle.xml" The new codes creates new circle

Comment: you can create the same drawable as circle.xml in code.  circle.xml gets compiled into a resource when you compile the app it does not stay xml.  so "change the stroke width for circle.xml" is not possible.

Answer (score 16):

Do like this:

1) Get the `TextView` using the usual `findViewById()` :

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resourceName);
```

2) Get the `Drawable` from `TextView` using `getBackground()` and cast it to `GradientDrawable`:

```
GradientDrawable backgroundGradient = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground();
```

3) Apply it a stroke using `setStroke()` method (pass it the width in pixel and the color):

```
backgroundGradient.setStroke(5, Color.BLACK);
```

Whole code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resourceName);
GradientDrawable backgroundGradient = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground();
backgroundGradient.setStroke(5, Color.BLACK);
```