# With Android, how can I change at runtime the stroke width of a line shape defined in XML

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, shapes

I have a plus sign defined in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="line"
        android:id="@+id/line1">
        <stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-90">
        <shape android:shape="line"
            android:id="@+id/line2">
            <stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

At runtime I sometimes want to change the `stroke` `width` from 15dp to something else.

My plus sign is added to a Button, with an id `move_button`:

```
        <Button
        android:background="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/move_button" />
```

I am able to programmatically change the `move_button` but I don't know how to set the `stroke` `width` on the line shapes with ids `line1` and `line2` at runtime.

This is what I have so far:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)moveButton.getBackground(); //this is not null
String horLine = "line1";
int horLineID = getResources().getIdentifier(horLine, "id", getPackageName()); //this gives an id for the horizontal line
```

I don't know what to do next to change the stroke widths.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647288/1390035) answer by eldivino87 solves a problem almost identical to mine but there is no `setStroke` method for `LayerDrawable`

Comment: I would try to set an id to the item in the layer instead of the shape.Then you can get the shape like layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(); You can cast it to ShapeDrawable, so you have access to a Paint object (getPaint()) and you can modify its stroke.

Comment: @LuisMiguelSierra Thanks very much Luis.  Actually your comment combined with eldivino87's answer gave me the solution.  The cast to `ShapeDrawable` gave a runtime exception but I'll put the code that works as an answer to help anyone else with this issue

Comment: use gradient drawable instead of layerdrawable. gradient drawable supports border color and width

Answer (score 1):

Moving the id to the List Item, as Luis suggested solves the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/line1">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/line2">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-90">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Then the code becomes:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)moveButton.getBackground(); 
String horLine = "line1";
int horLineID = getResources().getIdentifier(horLine, "id", getPackageName()); //this gives an id for the horizontal line
GradientDrawable hLine = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(horLineID);
hLine.setStroke(5, Color.BLACK);
```